# Do all that works for Ubuntu work for Lubuntu?

Tags: software-installation, lubuntu

How can I guess, when finding sw install instructions/suggestions for Ubuntu, if they are ok for the Lubuntu 16.04 version I've got on my pc? 
Thans!

Comment: The core of all desktop Ubuntu's (Ubuntu, Xubuntu, Kubuntu, Ubuntu-Mate, Lubuntu, Ubuntu-Budgie..) are the same so nearly every command will work in all.  There are differences though, eg. Ubuntu uses GNOME or Unity which are based on GTK+ 3, Kubuntu uses KDE & Qt, etc so libraries are different, and a small 'install' for a GTK based *Ubuntu maybe large for Kubuntu, a small install command for Kubuntu could be very large when using Lubuntu. Whilst the commands will work (eg. a `sudo apt-get install`) the effect could be different (for one or more flavors the download is small, others its huge)

Comment: Themes are different between DEsktops, so a theme for GTK+ based (gnome, unity..) you won't expect to work in Qt based Kubuntu, or Lubuntu. Hence whilst most commands will work perfectly in other flavors, there are some that won't in every flavor due differences in libs or config files etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The core of all desktop Ubuntu's (Ubuntu, Xubuntu, Kubuntu, Ubuntu-Mate, Lubuntu, Ubuntu-Budgie..) are the same so nearly every command will work in all flavors.

There are differences though, eg. Ubuntu uses GNOME (17.10) or Unity (14.04, 16.04) which are based on **GTK+ 3**, Kubuntu uses KDE & **Qt**, etc so libraries are different, and a small 'install' for a GTK+ based *Ubuntu maybe large for Kubuntu, a small install command for Kubuntu could be very large when using Lubuntu. Whilst the commands will work (eg. a sudo apt-get install) the effect could be different in installs, disk space & memory needed etc.  (more libs require more memory which can slow your system down; Lubuntu is light but using other flavor libs will stop it being light)

Themes are different between DEsktops, so a theme for GTK+ based (gnome, unity..) you won't expect to work in Qt based Kubuntu, or Lubuntu. Hence whilst most commands will work perfectly in other flavors, there are some that won't in every flavor due differences in libs or config files etc

*the following is an example in an attempt to explain a later question*

`kate` is a text editor for KDE (or K DEsktop) or an equivalent to leafpad as found in Lubuntu (I believe anyway). Kate being for KDE thus uses Qt libs. My system is Ubuntu 17.10 (with GNOME & Mate, thus using GTK+ 3 libs). I

```
  sudo apt install kate
```

which would install kate on any Ubuntu. When I hit enter it tells me

```
 "0 to upgrade, 135 to newly install .."
```

which is a huge warning to me its going to use libraries that aren't in my system. 1 for kate I'd expect, maybe 1-4 extra is okay; 135 is a red-flag. It may work, but will be inefficient (memory wise, use more disk space etc)

My system has 8gb of ram so It'll handle having KDE's Qt libs, plus GTK+ (v3) libs in memory, but if I was using my old eeepc (1gb ram which runs Lubuntu) I'd answer "N" (not continue, or abort the install) as on 1gb of ram it'd be inefficient (ie. laggy). Sorry I don't know a filter, and don't use GUI tools much, but terminal commands give tons of output & clues...

A text editor (eg. `kate`) is a small 'app', if I was to pick something like Libre Office (huge office suite, Writer, Calc, ....) I'd expect a larger number than 5 extra files (my guess was 15-30), a quick `dpkg -l libre* | grep ^ii|wc` (deb-package -list libre* | grep (show only lines starting with 'ii' or installed) | wc (word-count; where I only look at line count) tells me i have 28 such files installed (named libre*). My point is large apps/suites like LibreOffice will be higher than 5, but the 135 for my `kate` example is way to big.

I can recognize the package names for `kate` & recognize `libkf5*` (kde v5 framework), `libqt5*` (kde qt v5 libs) from the names etc. But even if you don't recognize the names (you'll get to pick/recognize them pretty quickly if you want to) - the summary package count makes it pretty easy.

Comment: Ok. Therefor, is there a way to "filter" install commands in order to get the proper installation without always have to bother people asking how to? As pretty obvious, I'm a newbie....

Comment: I'll try and help.  `kate` is a text editor for KDE (or K DEsktop) or an equivalent to `leafpad` as found in Lubuntu (I believe anyway). Kate being for KDE thus uses Qt libs. My system is Ubuntu 17.10 (with GNOME, Mate thus GTK+ 3 libs installed).  I `sudo apt install kate` which would install kate on any Ubuntu. When I hit enter it tells me "0 to upgrade, 135 to newly install" which is a huge warning to me its going to use libraries that aren't in my system. 1 for kate I'd expect, maybe 1-4 extra is okay; 135 is a red-flag. It may work, but will be inefficient (memory wise).

Comment: My system has 8gb of ram so It'll handle having KDE's Qt libs, plus GTK+ (v3) libs in memory, but if I was using my old eeepc (1gb ram which runs Lubuntu) I'd answer "N" (not continue, or abort the install) as on 1gb of ram it'd be inefficient (ie. laggy).  Sorry I don't know a filter, and don't use GUI tools much, but terminal commands give tons of output & clues...  (ps:  *prior comment may seem strange; Mate & Gnome are different DEsktops & 'flavors', but I've loaded both on my system, so I can pick which I want to use when I login*)

Comment: A text editor is a small 'app', if I was to pick something like Libre Office (huge office app, Writer, Calc, ....) I'd expect a larger number than 5 extra files (my guess was 15-30), a quick `dpkg -l libre* | grep ^ii|wc`  (deb-package -list libre* | grep (show only lines starting with 'ii' or installed) | wc (word-count; where I only look at line count) tells me i have 28 such files installed (named libre*).   My point is large apps/suites like LibreOffice will be higher than 5 (30 was pretty close), but the 135 for my `kate` example is way to big..

Comment: I can read the package names for `kate` & recognize libkf5* (kde v5 framework), libqt5* (kde qt v5 libs) from the names etc.  But even if you don't recognize the names (you'll get to pick/recognize them pretty quickly if you want to) - the summary package count makes it pretty easy.

Comment: "terminal commands give tons of output & clues" 
this really seems pretty interesting to me; I'll try to work it out.

From your example I'm also starting to get the point, but it'll take time. For instance, I quite don't get the difference(in your answer) between Libraries and Files, in order to estimate if a sw will work on my sistem.

Beside,  my problem is more this:
Trying to install libimobiledevice; I "sudo apt install libimobiledevice" and it answer: "impossible to find the libimobiledevice package"...
I get lost and have to ask; this way I'm always depending on someone else...

Comment: Does the answer mean that it is impossible to find it in my pc, therefore I should somehow download it? 

Anyway, should I be getting OT or making it too large for a single Question, please just  let me know...

Comment: Libraries are programs that have no real user interface (no gui, no terminal interface) but are called by other programs using APIs (application program interfaces), and if a library wasn't already in your system but is used by a app you're just installing (thus a dependency) it'll get installed (why `kate` installs tons of libs it needs if you're running mate/xfce/lxde/gnome/.. but will already be in your system if you were running kde/lxqt/.. (where installing `leafpad` would be a bad idea resource wise)

Comment: as for `libimobiledevice`; if I get issues with a package (be it app, library or anything) I search for it https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libimobiledevice  (you can reduce this to a single version; eg. 16.04 too).   It tells me there is `libimobiledevice-dev` or `libimobiledevice4`, `libimobiledevice6` etc.  I'd probably then re-check the source that tells me I need this file (is it old? was it renamed and a version number (4) put on it to allow a newer (6) version to also be used? or could be be they meant the -dev(eloper) version?